# key-value в treeview

Tags: c#, treeview

У меня есть данные.

```
Москва;4
Саратов;9
Киров;3
```

Есть ли у Treview свойство которое позволит мне хранить эти данные, но чтобы отображался только город, а в свойствах есть номер города

Вот например если занести в Dictionary эти данные, то очень удобно получить доступ сделав следующее dictionary["Москва"] // результат 4. Я думал может быть Dictionary занести в Treeview?

Answer (score 5):

У `TreeNode`есть свойство `TreeNode.Tag`, специально для целей хранения данных - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag(v=vs.110).aspx)

Оно так же есть у всех классов-наследников `Control`: [`Control.Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо за грамотный ответ!) Маленький вопрос вдогонку. А как быть с Listbox? Как в нем сделать чтобы одно отображалось, а другое было скрыто

Comment: @Radzhab654654 в `ListBox.Items` можно добавлять полноценные объекты, и задавать свойства для отображения и для получения данных через `DisplayMember` и `ValueMember`

Answer (score 3):

Winforms или Wpf? Если Wpf, то на viewmodel определяете св-ва Id, Name.
А в xaml прописываете:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Viewmodels}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"...
```

Answer (score 0):

*Данный ответ не предназначен для "продакшн" кода и как минимум за такое могут надавать по рукам. Но.. не весь код "продакшн" и иногда, когда надо хранить не только тэг, а времени и цели сделать "на века" нет, то:*

Один из **хаков**, записывать текст в дерево в виде:

```
Москва                             4
Саратов                              9
Киров                             3
```

При отрисовке все что не влезает справа обрежется. При обращении - берем последние N символов и переводим их в число.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) В принципе я так и сделал, но только когда наводишь на него там всплывает **Москва                             4**. Есть вариант убрать "предпросмотр" данных в treeview?

Comment: Это "ок" для лабораторной работы в универе, но давать это в виде ответа на stackoverflow, как совет для кода на проде - по меньшей мере невежливо.

Comment: Не весь код "прод" и иногда хак может быть целесообразнее. Пусть это будет одним из вариантов ответа.

Comment: Имхо Вы предложили неподдерживаемый костыль, актуальный для конкретной реализации treeview. И любой программист, который воспользуется Вашим советом, напишет однозначно плохой код. Придумать, как сделать криво, неподдерживаемо и плохо люди могут сами, а такие ресурсы, как stackoverflow - для правильных решений. Поэтому свой -1 я не убираю :)

Comment: @Arkady: В свое время мне этот костыль неплохо сэкономил время и позволил сделать нужную в деле программку. На SO людей много и не все даже могут придумать как посчитать остаток от деления числа. Даже примитивные казалось бы вещи, надо подсказывать. Правильность решения состоит из многих слагаемых, и идеальный код не всегда на первом месте. В любом случае, голосование на то и есть, чтобы показывать какие ответы/решения предпочтительние.